# Understanding the fine-tuning problem related to baryon asymmetry as an initial condition

Tags: cosmology, beyond-the-standard-model, fine-tuning, baryogenesis, leptogenesis

The reason for not assuming the Baryon asymmetry of the universe as an initial condition is often attributed to the following fine-tuning problem: If the baryon asymmetry had been an initial condition, then, for every 6,000,000 antiquarks, there should have been 6,000,001 quarks.

How are these numbers estimated? Is there a calculation which will dictate these numbers?

**Note:** I know there are other arguments for it and I understand them. But I'm particularly interested in understanding these numbers as mentioned in [this review](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.2962) (second paragraph, page 4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calculation is actually reasonably simple. [Most of the photons in the Universe are CMB photons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/196366/number-density-of-cmb-photons), and the number density of CMB photons has been measured to exquisite accuracy. There are about $N_\gamma = 4.11\times10^8\,{\rm m}^{-3}$. The [mass density of baryons](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Sept02/Roos/Roos4.html) has also been measured, both "directly" via elemental abundances and the Big Bang nucleosynthesis model, and "indirectly" from CMB analysis. It is $\Omega_{\rm b}\approx0.02$, where $\Omega_{\rm b}$ is the density in units of the critical density for closure $\rho_{\rm crit}=137.6\,{\rm M}_\odot\,{\rm kpc}^3$. I'll spare you all the unit conversion; under sensible assumptions for the composition of the baryons in the Universe, you get an average number density of about $N_{\rm bar} = 0.11\,{\rm m}^{-3}$. Taking the ratio of the two number densities, you find that for every baryon, there are $3.7\times10^9$ photons. $q\bar{q}$ annihilation [is complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation#Proton-antiproton_annihilation), but from what I surmise the result is $\mathcal{O}(1)$ photon per quark, so initially there would have been about $3.7\times10^{9}+1$ baryons worth of quarks for every $3.7\times10^{9}$ anti-baryons worth of quarks (noting that it takes both quarks and anti-quarks to make a typical baryon, or anti-baryon).

I think the numbers 6,000,000 and 6,000,001 in the article you linked must be typos (should rather be ~6,000,000,000), as I can't think of anything that would account for 3 orders of magnitude difference between the (current) ratio $N_{\rm b}/N_\gamma$ and the (initial) ratio $(N_{\rm b} - N_{\bar{\rm b}})/N_{\rm b}$. If you look around the literature, both popular and technical, on the topic, the figure '1 part per billion', rather than ~1 part per million, is the one that gets quoted.

Comment: I just bounced this off one of my particle physics friends and it's reinforced my conviction that the article has a typo/error.

Answer (score 3):

To start, it is important to notice that a statement  like "For each x antiquarks, there are x+1 quarks" is vacuous **unless you specify the instant at which you are looking at the system**. To give an example, if you start with 100 antiquarks for every 101 quark, there will be a time when you'll have 50 for every 51, and finally 0 for every 1.

This said, I'd recommend to disregard this unfortunate statement in an otherwise awesome review and turn to Kolb and Turner's *The Early Universe*, where a similar comment is made (near equation 6.2, page 159):

> Although the baryon asymmetry is maximal today,
>   i.e., no antimatter, at high temperatures ($T \gtrsim 1\,\textrm{GeV}$) thermal quark-antiquark pairs were present in great numbers ($n_q \sim n_{\bar q} \sim n_\gamma$), so that the
>   baryon asymmetry observed today corresponds to a tiny quark-antiquark
>   asymmetry at early times ($t \lesssim 10^{-6}\,\textrm{s}$):
>   $$\frac{n_q-n_{\bar q}}{n_q} \simeq 3 \times 10^{-8}\,.$$
>   That is, **for every 30 million antiquarks, there were 30 million and 1 quarks present**! A very tiny asymmetry indeed.

Unlike Davidson, Nardi and Nir, these authors refer to a specific time, namely around and before $t \sim 10^{-6}$ seconds, corresponding to temperatures about and above $1\,\textrm{GeV}$.

---

Lets take a stab at computing their quoted value. At such time in the history of the Universe, particles such as the light quarks move relativistically, and in this limit $n_q \simeq n_{\bar q} \simeq \frac{3}{4} n_\gamma$ (see eq. 3.52 of the same book).

Additionally, the density of photons $n_\gamma$ and the entropy density $s$ are related at all times by (chapter 3.4):
$$s = \frac{\pi^4\, g_{*s}}{45\, \zeta(3)} \,n_\gamma\simeq 1.8\, g_{*s}\,n_\gamma\,.$$

Here $g_{*s}$ is a function of time. For temperatures around $1\,\textrm{GeV}$ one has $g_{*s} \simeq 62$ according to [this detailed StackExchange answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/170682/50705). Hence,

$$ 
\frac{n_q - n_{\bar q}}{n_q} 
\simeq  \frac{3 n_B - 3 n_{\bar B}}{\frac{3}{4} n_\gamma} 
\simeq 4 \frac{n_B - n_{\bar B}}{n_\gamma} 
\simeq 4 \frac{s}{n_\gamma}    \frac{n_B - n_{\bar B}}{s} 
\simeq 4 \, (1.8 \cdot 62) \,  Y_{\Delta B}\,,$$
where $Y_{\Delta B} \equiv (n_B - n_{\bar B})/{s}$ is measured to be $\simeq 9 \times 10^{-11}$ **today** according to (1.2) of Davidson, Nardi and Nir. The nice thing is that this quantity is **unchanged** from the moment baryon violating interactions become inactive (way before $t \sim 10^{-6}\,\textrm{s}$ in a log scale), and assuming no entropy production.

So we can plug it in and get:
$$ 
\frac{n_q - n_{\bar q}}{n_q} 
\simeq  4 \cdot 1.8 \cdot 62 \cdot  9 \times 10^{-11} \simeq 4 \times 10^{-8}
\,,$$
which is in good enough agreement with what is quoted in the book :)

Comment: "if you start with 100 antiquarks for every 101 quark, there will be a time when you'll have 50 for every 51, and finally 0 for every 1" I don't follow this. Are you talking about the number in the fixed volume? Because once the production/annihilation reactions freeze out, the number of particles is constant, and the number density of photons and baryons (quarks) scales in the same way.

Comment: @Kyle Sorry, I was just giving a toy example (particles and antiparticles in, if you wish, a box with annihilations always happening and from which photons are removed) to illustrate the need to specify a time/temperature. In fact, as you point out, interactions freeze out in an expanding Universe :). Kolb and Turner have a nice discussion on this in their chapter 5.2 "Freeze Out: Origin of Species", namely pp. 127-128.