# graph relativistic degrees of freedom

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, universe, thermal-radiation, degrees-of-freedom

I'm trying to graph the relativistic degrees of freedom, which should look like the figure

[image]

And I am trying to guide me with this Phys.SE answer: [Number $g(T)$ of relativistic degrees of freedom as a function of temperature $T$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169425/). However I don't understand how could I get a smooth function, because from what I understood, when the thermal energy goes below the rest energy of a particle, it decouples and its effective degrees stop contribuiting. So I actually get a piecewise function that goes like this

[image]

Moreover, some of the valleys do not match. In the question cited, the approved answer states that $\textit{below 100 MeV all quarks decoupled}$ but it doesn't seem like, since s d and u quarks all have rest energy less than 100 MeV

Comment: the line between 1e-1 and 1e-5 is actually also escalonated, plotting more points is enough. But the smoothness remains a question